# Creating a PDF/X-3 conforming file based on Koma-Script "scrbook" class fails while it works for standard "book" class

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, scrbook, pdfx

I am trying to set up a LaTeX file using the "scrbook" class from the Koma-Script so that the resulting PDF when compiled with `pdflatex` complies with the PDF/X-3 standard for professional printing machines. The problem is that the created file contains some undesired "actions" such as opening and going to a page. Interestingly, the problem does not occurr when instead of the `scrbook` class the standard `book` class is used.

Here is a MWE of the problem when I use the `scrbook` class:

```
\documentclass[a4]{scrbook}
\pdfminorversion=3
\usepackage[x-3,pdf13]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
\part{My Part Header}\label{Kap1}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

The metadata file required for "pdfx" looks as follows:

```
\Title{My book}
\Author{Th. Author}
\Language{en-GB}
\Keywords{Topic1 \sep Topic2}
\Publisher{International Nonsense}
```

The `tex` file compiles without problems. I then use the Acrobat Pro Preflight functionality to check conformity with the PDF/X-3 standard, getting the following result:

[image: PDF contains "actions" that violate PDF/X-3 the standard]

This "additional action" upon opening of the PDF file is what I want to avoid. Interestingly, if I use the standard `book` class as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4]{book}
\pdfminorversion=3
\usepackage[x-3,pdf13]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
\part{My Part Header}\label{Kap1}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

then the problem does not occur:

[image: No problem here!]

It therefore seems that the problem is related to (my usage of) the `scrbook` Koma script. However, I very much want/need to use the `scrbook` document class.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of that problem of the additional actions? They seem to be related to sectioning commands such as `\part{}`, `\section{}` etc., which I need for my document.

In addition, any general recommendations about how to achieve PDF/X-3 conformity are highly welcome.

Comment: try `\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false]{scrbook}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry to ask, is (PDF-X1a) this possible in `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF`? I need this clarification, please....

Comment: @MadyYuvi no idea, probably yes, but I don't know how well pdfx supports this route. But why don't you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of the KOMA classes load the bookmark package which adds actions to the pdf. You can suppress this with the following option:

```
\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false]{scrbook}
```

Comment: True. The reason for the failed Preflight test is that those actions are forbidden in all PDF/X up to at least 5. `book` does not generate bookmarks by default.